# Access urandom device get "permission denied", why?

Tags: linux, random

I can create a new urandom device on a some directory (`test_urandom` in below example), and it works as expected. E.g.

```
test_urandom$ sudo mknod -m 0444 ./urandom c 1 9
test_urandom$ ls -l
total 0
cr--r--r-- 1 root root 1, 9 Jun  9 09:06 urandom
test_urandom$ head -c 10 ./urandom 
�׫O1�9�^
```

However, if I create the same device node in another directory, which in my case is an ext4 filesystem on a LVM (Logical Volume Management), it failed and system complained with `permission denied.`

```
test_urandom_lvm$ sudo mknod -m 0444 ./urandom c 1 9
test_urandom_lvm$ ls -l
total 0
cr--r--r-- 1 root root 1, 9 Jun  9 09:06 urandom
test_urandom_lvm$ head -c 10 ./urandom
head: cannot open ‘./urandom’ for reading: Permission denied
```

If I am allowed to create a device in the filesystem, why not allowed to read the device? What caused the permission denied? What changes is needed to make it work?

Comment: There is no such thing as an "LVM filesystem". LVM is not a filesystem, it is a block device. A filesystem doesn't care (and in fact doesn't know) what kind of block device it sits on, and a block device doesn't care (and in fact doesn't know) what filesystem is on it (if there even is a filesystem on it).

Comment: LVM doesn't matter. What is the filesystem type? What options is it mounted with?

Comment: @ Jörg Thanks for the clarification regarding LVM. I have updated the question.  My key point here is why a urandom device created in a filesystem which is mounted on a  LVM logic block device doesn't work? What kind of permission is needed to make it work?

Comment: @ ephemient:  Thanks ephemient. You pointed out the root cause. The filesystem is mounted with 'user' option which implies 'nodev" (Do not interpret character or block special devices on the file system)

Comment: No, you still do not understand. LVM has absolutely nothing whatsoever to do with filesystems. It doesn't know nor care about filesystems, it doesn't know nor care about files, it doesn't know nor care about device nodes, it doesn't know nor care about permissions, it doesn't know nor care about users. LVM is a block device, block devices and filesystems live on two completely different layers of abstraction. It is absolutely, completely, totally, 100% impossible for LVM to have anything to do with your problem. Zip. Nada. Zilch. Nothing. LVM *cannot possibly* be the source of your problem.

Comment: @JörgWMittag You are absolutely right. I rephrased the title and description to better reflect the nature of the root cause. One thing I still not clear is why it allows me to create the device in a filesystem with nodev option enabled in the first place?  At least it should issue a warning.

Answer (score 1):

The filesystem is mounted with the `nodev` option, which inhibits block and character special device operation. Mounting it `dev` will allow them to work.